# CASE statement syntax error in SAP Lumira / Freehand SQL

Tags: sql, case-statement, sap-erp, sap-lumira

I’m using SAP Lumira desktop and "Query with SQL (Freehand SQL)", connected to SAP ECC. I try to extend the query with a case statement but run into errors as below:

```
SELECT "VBUK-UVALS",
           CASE ("VBUK-UVALS") WHEN 'A' THEN 'Closed'
                               WHEN 'B' THEN 'Open'
                               ELSE 'Other'
           END AS "ColumnA"
FROM   "Local"."INFOSET"."ZCA_TESTAR"
```

> Syntax error in SQL query:
>   [line 2:31 missing FROM at 'WHEN'][line 2:36 missing EOF at "A"]

It would be very appreciated if any could guide me through this

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, your syntax is wrong. A `case` expression has only one `case` keyword, and can have multiple `when` clauses of the different values you're evaluating (and an optional single `else` clause):

```
SELECT "VBUK-UVALS",
       CASE ("VBUK-UVALS") WHEN 'A' THEN 'Closed'
                           WHEN 'B' THEN 'Open' -- CASE ("VBUK-UVALS") removed
                           ELSE 'Other'
       END AS "ColumnA"
FROM   "Local"."INFOSET"."ZCA_TESTAR"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, to many “CASE”, It was a mistake by me when wrote the case.
The Query is stated as followed with the same error message

```
SELECT "VBUK-UVALS",
       CASE ("VBUK-UVALS") WHEN 'A' THEN 'Closed'
                           WHEN 'B' THEN 'Open'
                           ELSE 'Other'
       END AS "ColumnA"
FROM   "Local"."INFOSET"."ZCA_TESTAR"
```

Syntax error in SQL query:
[line 2:27 missing FROM at 'WHEN'][line 2:32 missing EOF at "A"]